# OpenGL LWJGL Invalid Enum

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm tring to implement a Shader in a LWJGL Application.
Got an 'invalid Enum' Exception if i try to attach the Shader. 
Okay, Code talke more....

```
private void attach(int progID) {
    GL20.glAttachShader(progID,  vertShaderID);
    GL20.glAttachShader(progID, fragShaderID);
    System.out.println("Tester: " + GLU.gluErrorString(GL11.glGetError()));
    GL20.glLinkProgram(progID);
    System.out.println("Tester: " + GLU.gluErrorString(GL11.glGetError()));
    if(GL20.glGetShader(progID, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("error during linking shaders! " + GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(progID, 1000) + " " + GLU.gluErrorString(GL11.glGetError()));
    }

    GL20.glValidateProgram(progID);
    System.out.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(progID, 1000));
    System.out.println("Tester: " + GLU.gluErrorString(GL11.glGetError()));
    System.out.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(progID, 1000));
    if(GL20.glGetShader(progID, GL20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("error during validating shaders! " + GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(progID, 1000) + " " + GLU.gluErrorString(GL11.glGetError()));
    }

}
```

produces output:

Tester: No error

Tester: No error

Validation successfull

Tester: Invalid Enum

Validation successfull

So i follow the source of Exception to this Function.
What does this Validation Function? If the program Log is 'Validation successfull', what produces this Error? Or is that Error called from any other Situation where I used a GL Function in the Application? And what means The Invlaid Enum Error? It means that i used a GL Type wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_LINK_STATUS` is not something you can query with `glGetShader{iv} (...)`, that is for shader status. You probably meant to use `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` for each of your shaders.

```
GL20.glGetShader (vertShaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
GL20.glGetShader (fragShaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
```

`GL_LINK_STATUS` is only a valid enum for `glGetProgram{iv} (...)`:

```
GL20.glGetProgram (progID, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS);
```

Ideally you should check the compile status for each shader, and then the link status after linking all shaders using the functions and enums I mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, I check the Compilation Status in another function for loading the file and get shader source

Comment: Okay, well in any case. This is the cause of your error. You cannot pass `GL_LINK_STATUS` to `glGetShader (...)`, or it will give you this error message. I have explained what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: Ah okay, i see what you mean, have erased the both glGetShader(....) and replaced with yours. Error is gone, thank you so much :D